# Shortening a clickable url stored inside a variable

Tags: php

This is my current code:

```
$parcels = $api->parcels->get(); 

$url = (array_values($parcels)[0]['label']['label_printer']);
$goToUrl = $api->getUrl($url);

$goToUrl = str_replace('/api/v2//api/v2/', '/api/v2/', $goToUrl);
print_r($goToUrl);
echo "<br />";
echo $url;
```

Why do I use `str_replace()`? because I am intending to redirect to `$goToUrl` and this is not working because the current API is giving me the link wrong.

This is my output:

```
https://api_key:api_secret@panel.sendcloud.nl/api/v2/labels/label_printer/1369315
```

Code where it's used in the email:

```
$email_body = ("This is Label: " . ($parcel_name) . " |OrderId: " . ($parcel_order_number) . "\n\n See Label: " . $goToUrl );
```

Current situation this url get's emailed, and in the mail I would like it to be a clickable link instead of the entire url. Even only maybe the last part is good enough:

```
label/label_printer/1369315
```

i've seen **preg_replace** but never used it before so I find it very difficult to understand it.

Comment: Uh, what? Shortening the URL will cause it to fail / missing parts of the url? I'm not sure I understand, why not just wrap it in `<a href="<fullURL>">Click me</a>` ??

Comment: @Epodax Yes the url should stay intact, proper situation is what you describe but it's inside phpmailer where the variable get used. I don't see the opportunity to use html?

Comment: `$mailer->isHtml(true);` enables HTML or `$mailer->MsgHTML($body);`

Comment: @Epodax your comments helped me achieve the answer, so the setting html to true is what started the issue because my html was not working. Can you post it as an answer ? Then I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To enable HTML in phpmailer you have to use

```
$mailer->isHtml(true); //Enables html in the regular body.
```

Or

```
$mailer->MsgHTML($body); //Enables and SETS the message body with HTML.
```

You can see http://phpmailer.worxware.com/ for examples / guides on how to use phpmailer with html / configure it properly.